# Convert ajax function to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I would like to convert this ajax function to a jquery function but im not sure how it would be done in jquery

```
function ajax_posta() {
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "javas.php";


    hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send("num=" + (--num)); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src = 'loading.gif' height =     '30'     width = '30'>";

}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.eventer.button').click(function () {
        var self = this;
        $.post('javas.php', function (data) {
            $(self).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
        })
    });
}
)
;
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for putting up with my initial sloppiness :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there

```
$.ajax('javas.php', {
    success: function(response) {
          $(".status").html(response);
    }, 
    data: "num=" + (--num)
});
```

If these are the only two pieces of data you need to send to your request, you could just use `$.post`, but the advantage here is that if you ever want to specify more options, like contentType, all you'd have to do is add it to the existing options object.

Comment: please may you explain a little more :D

Comment: small problem, status is not an Id it is a class

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I added in your content type like your original code, and I made the callback more similar to the original.

Comment: +1, but I think this content-type is default for post, so it isn't necessary.

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I assumed it was an id since you were calling it with getElementById in your original code.

Comment: -1: Since adding the content type is irrelevant (since that is the default) and *you got the property name for it wrong*! **and** you have *thrown away all the data being sent to the server*!

Comment: can i make it an id, you see the eventer class is being created in while loop so there are many duplicates, Ids are supposed to be unique right? is there any other way i can do it

Comment: must i replace the entire ajax_posta funtion with what is above?

Comment: @Quentin - you're right - I missed his input to the server.  I'm sloppy today :(

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I'm just trying to show you how to use $.post and $.ajax - that's what you wanted, right?  You wanted to convert your original xhr request into one using jQuery?

Comment: im trying to replace ajax_posta()

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I updated my original answer to include your num parameter in the same way you were passing it originally.  That should get you pretty close to replacing your original function.

Comment: would it be ok that i make multiple ids of eventer and status as these  elements are being created in a while loop?

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - multiple class ids?  Sure.  Multiple id ids?  No.  All IDs must be unique on your page

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - yes, I believe so

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - no problem.  I'm really sorry my original answer was so half-baked.  Hopefully you've got some good info now :)

Comment: @AdamRackis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540305/jquery-on-click-function-nothing-happening please check this out

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I answered that question - yet another problem with this answer.  This was one of the worst answers I've ever made - really sorry