# jQuery on click function nothing happening

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, class

This jQuery function is meant to post the value of num to a PHP page and then echo it in the correct status class, any ideas why nothing is happening, I have downloaded jQuery and called the file further up (not displayed here)

Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
<script>
 var num = 1;
                function ajax_post(){ 
$.ajax('javas.php', {
success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
}, 
data: "num=" + (++num)
});
}

function ajax_posta(){
$.ajax('javas.php', {
success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
}, 
data: "num=" + (--num)
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.eventer > .button').click(function () {
    ajax_post();
});
alert("lol");
});


</script>
```

This is what i have, this is my php code concerning the classes.

```
<div id = 'eventcontainer' >

<?php

//Getting posts from DB

$event1 = mysql_query("SELECT post,date,memid FROM postaction WHERE memid = '$id' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5;");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($event1))
{




$event = $row1['post'];
$timeposted = $row1['date'];

$eventmemdata = mysql_query("SELECT id,firstname FROM users WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");

while($rowaa = mysql_fetch_array($eventmemdata))
{
    $name = $rowaa['firstname'];
    $eventlist = "$event <br> $name";
}

echo " <div class = 'eventer'> $timeposted <br>$eventlist <input name='myBtn'       type='submit' value='increment' onClick='javascript:ajax_post();'>
<input name='lol' type='submit' value='dec' onClick='javascript:ajax_posta();'></div>
<div class = 'status'></div>";
echo "<br>";

}


?>
```

Comment: please add your markup as well.

Comment: Try writing $('.eventer > .button') to console and see if it returns any dom objects. If it does, try $('.eventer > .button').first().click() on the console this time. Have you checked the php for errors? Is it returning anything? As I can see you are not posting anything to php at the moment. Plus the usage of the $.post() command in the functions (as I know of) are wrong, it looks like you have mixed it with the $.ajax() call. You should check out the examples in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$.post` change it to [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You could re-arrange the parameters to get it to work with $.post, but it looks like the code you have is meant to be run with [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Also, inside of here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.eventer > .button').click(function () {
        var self = this;
        $.post('javas.php', function (data) {
            $(self).closest('.eventer').find('.status').html(data);
        })
    });
    alert("lol");
});
```

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.eventer > .button').click(function () {
        ajax_post();
    });
    alert("lol");
});
```

Comment: must i keep it in the ajax_post() tags for the on click function?

Comment: ajax_post() looks good - you just need to change $.post to $.ajax.  Also see my last edit for one other potential problem

Comment: i posted all the relevant parts, i cant seem to find anything thats wrong

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - create a jsfiddle recreating the problem

Comment: maybe .button must be .submit?

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - you need to create a jsFiddle.  At the very least you have some major problem with your script that's preventing your lol alert from showing

Comment: @foshoeiyyy http://jsfiddle.net/  You use it to reproduce your javascript problems so others can help you debug

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - you can't put PHP in there.  You need to the actual html / script that's failing.  Once you know what's wrong with the html / script, you can fix your PHP

Comment: Took me awhile to spot it - you misspelled function in your document.ready handler

Answer (score 0):

If you try to put an alert in the click action, what does it happen ?

Perhaps your action isn't added on the object you think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the order of the parameters in the call to $.post wrong. It should be:

```
$.post("url", { data:'something' }, function(result){
    //callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing up the jQuery post and ajax methods.  Try adding the data argument (your num variable) in your post.

```
$('.eventer > .button').click(function () {
    var self = this;
    $.post('javas.php', num,function (data) {
        $(self).closest('.eventer').find('.status').html(data);
    })
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/